# Duda respecto a las constantes de tipo int

Tags: c++

Debo realizar un programa (utilizando funciones) el cual se le ingrese el numero (entero) deseado por pantalla y este lo convierta en números romanos. Lo que ocurre es que no se logra ejecutar el programa por estos errores:

[image: Imagen de los errores]

Soy consciente de que todavía no he llamado a las funciones, pero lo veo innecesario por el momento ya que sin nisiquiera llamarlas, ya me tira error y me gustaría entender el porque de los problemas que se presentaron por lo cual agradecería mucho si me podrían explicar, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numero;

int unidades (int){
    unidades = numero % 10; // 1
    numero /= 10; // 389 
    switch(unidades){
        case 1: cout<<"I";break;
        case 2: cout<<"II";break;
        case 3: cout<<"III";break;
        case 4: cout<<"IV";break;
        case 5: cout<<"V";break;
        case 6: cout<<"VI";break;
        case 7: cout<<"VII";break;
        case 8: cout<<"VIII";break;
        case 9: cout<<"IX";break;
    }
}

int decenas (int){
    decenas = numero % 10; // 9
    numero /= 10; // 38
    switch(decenas){
        case 1: cout<<"X";break;
        case 2: cout<<"XX";break;
        case 3: cout<<"XXX";break;
        case 4: cout<<"XL";break;
        case 5: cout<<"L";break;
        case 6: cout<<"LX";break;
        case 7: cout<<"LXX";break;
        case 8: cout<<"LXXX";break;
        case 9: cout<<"XC";break;
    }
}

int centenas (int){
    centenas = numero % 10; // 8
    numero /= 10; // 3
    switch(centenas){
        case 1: cout<<"C";break;
        case 2: cout<<"CC";break;
        case 3: cout<<"CCC";break;
        case 4: cout<<"CD";break;
        case 5: cout<<"D";break;
        case 6: cout<<"DC";break;
        case 7: cout<<"DCC";break;
        case 8: cout<<"DCCC";break;
        case 9: cout<<"CM";break;
    }
}

int millar (int){
    millar = numero; // 3
    switch(millar){
        case 1: cout<<"M";break;
        case 2: cout<<"MM";break;
        case 3: cout<<"MMM";break;
        
    }
}



int main (){

    int numero;

    cout<<"Ingrese un numero entero para convertilo en romano: "<<endl;
    cin>>numero; // 3891 


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Disculpen, me podrían explicar por qué no se anexa la imagen? :(

Comment: La rodeadste con  ```, entonces el sitio lo toma como codigo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: El codigo no compila porque tratas de usar las variables `unidades`, `decenas`, `centenas` y `millares` sin declararlas.

Comment: prueba con que la funcion sea del mismo tipo que el int

Comment: Me pregunto por qué haces que las funciones tengan parámetros si no los usas ni les das un nombre.

Comment: Ya implemente lo que me comentaron, les agradezco mucho

Comment: La pregunta podría considerarse parcialmente duplicada. Muestras unos problemas similares a los de tu otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/534165/169744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error es un poco absurdo pero muy fácil de entender:

- En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las funciones tienen un tipo de dato determinado por su retorno y sus parámetros, una función que devuelve un entero y recibe un entero tiene tipo `int(int)`.
- El nombre de una función es convertible implícitamente a un puntero a función.
- El puntero a una función que devuelve un entero y recibe un entero es `int(*)(int)`.

En todas tus funciones, en la primera línea usas el nombre de función como si fuese una variable:

```
int unidades (int){
    unidades = numero % 10; // 1
//  ^^^^^^^^ <-- 'unidades' es una función 'int(int)', se convierte a 'int(*)(int)'.
    numero /= 10; // 389 
    switch(unidades){
```

Seguramente querías declarar una variable en lugar de usar el nombre de la función:

```
int unidades (int){
    int unidades = numero % 10; // 1
    numero /= 10; // 389 
    switch(unidades){
```

Y probablemente querías usar un parámetro en cada función en lugar de usar una variable global:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int unidades (int numero) {
    int unidades = numero % 10; // 1
    numero /= 10; // 389 
    switch(unidades){
        case 1: cout<<"I";break;
        case 2: cout<<"II";break;
        case 3: cout<<"III";break;
        case 4: cout<<"IV";break;
        case 5: cout<<"V";break;
        case 6: cout<<"VI";break;
        case 7: cout<<"VII";break;
        case 8: cout<<"VIII";break;
        case 9: cout<<"IX";break;
    }
}

int decenas (int numero){
    int decenas = numero % 10; // 9
    numero /= 10; // 38
    switch(decenas){
        case 1: cout<<"X";break;
        case 2: cout<<"XX";break;
        case 3: cout<<"XXX";break;
        case 4: cout<<"XL";break;
        case 5: cout<<"L";break;
        case 6: cout<<"LX";break;
        case 7: cout<<"LXX";break;
        case 8: cout<<"LXXX";break;
        case 9: cout<<"XC";break;
    }
}

int centenas (int numero){
    int centenas = numero % 10; // 8
    numero /= 10; // 3
    switch(centenas){
        case 1: cout<<"C";break;
        case 2: cout<<"CC";break;
        case 3: cout<<"CCC";break;
        case 4: cout<<"CD";break;
        case 5: cout<<"D";break;
        case 6: cout<<"DC";break;
        case 7: cout<<"DCC";break;
        case 8: cout<<"DCCC";break;
        case 9: cout<<"CM";break;
    }
}

int millar (int numero){
    int millar = numero; // 3
    switch(millar){
        case 1: cout<<"M";break;
        case 2: cout<<"MM";break;
        case 3: cout<<"MMM";break;
        
    }
}
```