# Problema al llamar a una función en C++

Tags: c++

Debo realizar un programa (utilizando funciones) el cual se le ingrese el numero (entero) deseado por pantalla y este lo convierta en números romanos. Lo que ocurre es que al momento de llamar a las funciones, estas no se ejecutan como esperaba.

Es probable que las este usando de manera equivocada, entonces agradecería que me explicaran como podría ajustar mi programa para que se ejecute correctamente

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numero;

int unidades (int){
    int unidades;
    unidades = numero % 10; // 1
    numero /= 10; // 389 
    switch(unidades){
        case 1: cout<<"I";break;
        case 2: cout<<"II";break;
        case 3: cout<<"III";break;
        case 4: cout<<"IV";break;
        case 5: cout<<"V";break;
        case 6: cout<<"VI";break;
        case 7: cout<<"VII";break;
        case 8: cout<<"VIII";break;
        case 9: cout<<"IX";break;
    }
}

int decenas (int){
    int decenas;
    decenas = numero % 10; // 9
    numero /= 10; // 38
    switch(decenas){
        case 1: cout<<"X";break;
        case 2: cout<<"XX";break;
        case 3: cout<<"XXX";break;
        case 4: cout<<"XL";break;
        case 5: cout<<"L";break;
        case 6: cout<<"LX";break;
        case 7: cout<<"LXX";break;
        case 8: cout<<"LXXX";break;
        case 9: cout<<"XC";break;
    }
}

int centenas (int){
    int centenas;
    centenas = numero % 10; // 8
    numero /= 10; // 3
    switch(centenas){
        case 1: cout<<"C";break;
        case 2: cout<<"CC";break;
        case 3: cout<<"CCC";break;
        case 4: cout<<"CD";break;
        case 5: cout<<"D";break;
        case 6: cout<<"DC";break;
        case 7: cout<<"DCC";break;
        case 8: cout<<"DCCC";break;
        case 9: cout<<"CM";break;
    }
}

int millar (int){
    int millar;
    millar = numero; // 3
    switch(millar){
        case 1: cout<<"M";break;
        case 2: cout<<"MM";break;
        case 3: cout<<"MMM";break;
        
    }
}



int main (){

    int numero;

    cout<<"Ingrese un numero entero para convertilo en romano: "<<endl;
    cin>>numero; // 3891 

    unidades(numero);
    decenas(numero);
    centenas(numero);
    millar(numero);


    return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutar el programa, este mi pide el numero y después de ingresarlo finaliza. No hace nada de lo que está en las funciones.

Comment: las funciones deben ser declaradas con esta sintaxis `<tipo_de_retorno> <nombre_de_funcion>(<tipo_de_dato> <nombre de parametro>)`. En tu caso sería para la primera función `int unidades (int unidades)` y lo mismo para otras funciones. Aparte de especificar el tipo de dato debes colocarle nombre al parámetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observaciones:

- Las funciones están mal definidas.
- La variable global `numero` no es la misma que la variable local `numero`.
- Puedes definir las variables en la misma línea que las declaras.
- Los números romanos se escriben al revés. Comienzas por el dígito más grande  y terminas por el más pequeño.

Las funciones se **declaran** (indicas su existencia y no defines su comportamiento) de la siguiente manera:

```
tipo_de_retorno nombre(parámetros);
```

Los parámetros se declaran de forma ordenada con su tipo y opcionalmente su nombre.

Ejemplo de una función que recibe dos enteros y devuelve un entero:

```
int suma(int a, int b);
```

Puedes omitir el nombre de los parámetros, esta expresión es equivalente a la anterior.

```
int suma(int, int);
```

Ejemplo de una función que no recibe parámetros ni devuelve nada:

```
void funcion();
```

Como puedes ver, `void` significa que no devuelve nada.

---

Las funciones se **definen** de la siguiente manera:

```
tipo_de_retorno nombre(parámetros){
}
```

Los parámetros se indican de forma ordenada con su tipo y su nombre (no puedes omitirlo como en la declaración). Y si la función tiene un tipo de retorno distinto de `void`, debes devolver un valor del mismo tipo con `return`.

Ejemplo de una función que recibe dos enteros y devuelve un entero:

```
int suma(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Ejemplo de una función que recibe un entero y no devuelve nada:

```
void imprimir(int n){
    std::cout << n << '\0';
}
```

Suponiendo que no quieres devolver nada, el código queda más o menos así:

```
void unidades (int numero){
    ...
}

void decenas (int numero){
    ...
}

void centenas (int numero){
    ...
}

void millar (int numero){
    ...
}
```

---

Todavía hay un problema. En las funciones modificas el parámetro `numero`:

```
numero /= 10;
```

Entiendo que lo que quieres es modificar la variable `numero` de la función `main`. Pero el parámetro solo contiene una copia de tu variable.

Para solucionarlo se me ocurren dos opciones:

- Pasar los parámetros por referencia, de este modo la variable original se ve afectada:

  ```
    void unidades (int &numero){
        ...
    }

    void decenas (int &numero){
        ...
    }

    void centenas (int &numero){
        ...
    }

    void millar (int &numero){
        ...
    }
  ```

La desventaja de esta solución es que no sirve si quieres llamar la función con un literal:

```
unidades(1000); // Obtienes un error
```

- Hacer tus funciones sin tener que cambiar el valor de la variable original.

  ```
    void unidades(int numero){
        int unidades = numero % 10;
        ...
    }

    void decenas(int numero){
        int decenas = (numero / 10) % 10;
        ...
    }

    void centenas(int numero){
        int centenas = (numero / 100) % 10;
        ...
    }

    void millar(int numero){
        int millar = (numero / 1000) % 10;
        ...
    }
  ```

Puedes probar el programa con las últimas correcciones [aquí](https://tio.run/##jZVNT4MwGMfvfIonMyZ4MLoXdY5tl3IxgavptZZmNkIhpcyD2WfHspVJJ13aC8nz/Er/7Y8XWlX3NCdi17Y3XNC8yRiseVkryUixDYKm5mIHghSsrghlUKssCoJ9yTNoBM9IxuqQCwWiKZgs734C0KMr9F3YmB7cwvQxOvbrb67oZ9gjZlY3KKkZTFdAy0bBeg2Tt0kEHzrLV2QzsyHjguYW5KIWQ@rdAT0NIBfzPGRcq71YkIta2pQLex1GxzZ0CA5GVMYoE8ThyTS1ptB4etCe7v7bMuA1WdhDFsYesrCTGsrCiYesxENWgj1kJc5MS5vCHrIwcsnSh6zctvruha4xXz16TRjyEIaQhzDkpIbCUOwhLPYQFiMPYbEz09KmkIcwlLqEFTzPiRzXdepdyhqzdSKvuUo9XKWph6s0HdvLMS7hAkId4rwBE3sDOu2x@Pe5ETvJ9J0b0UPd86YvFZFEY2LPpOJ5VwZZFkSUK5h0M5nI8tO6VK@23Zrp5v7mNM1JGq5/Jaxq/1Wziud/0rl6LEumGim6TRzadjqbL4Jf).

Comment: Infinitas gracias por explicarme todo tan detallado, me colaborará muchisimo para futuros proyectos!!! :D ya entendí todito

Answer (score 1):

Estimado varios problemas:

- La variable int numero la declara primero global, luego local en main.
- Las llamadas a las funciones usan como parámetro la variable número, local a main, pero no se asignan correctamente en la definición de las funciones.
- Las funciones deberían devolver un entero, no lo hacen, esto también es problema.

Les paso una version modificada, hay muchas mejoras aun por hacer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int unidades (int mi_numero){
    int unidades;
    unidades = mi_numero % 10; // 1
    mi_numero /= 10; // 389

    switch(unidades){
        case 1: cout<<"I";break;
        case 2: cout<<"II";break;
        case 3: cout<<"III";break;
        case 4: cout<<"IV";break;
        case 5: cout<<"V";break;
        case 6: cout<<"VI";break;
        case 7: cout<<"VII";break;
        case 8: cout<<"VIII";break;
        case 9: cout<<"IX";break;
    }
    return mi_numero;
}

int decenas (int mi_numero){
    int decenas;
    decenas = mi_numero % 10; // 9

    mi_numero /= 10; // 38
    switch(decenas){
        case 1: cout<<"X";break;
        case 2: cout<<"XX";break;
        case 3: cout<<"XXX";break;
        case 4: cout<<"XL";break;
        case 5: cout<<"L";break;
        case 6: cout<<"LX";break;
        case 7: cout<<"LXX";break;
        case 8: cout<<"LXXX";break;
        case 9: cout<<"XC";break;
    }
    return mi_numero;
}

int centenas (int mi_numero){
    int centenas;
    centenas = mi_numero % 10; // 8
    mi_numero /= 10; // 3
    switch(centenas){
        case 1: cout<<"C";break;
        case 2: cout<<"CC";break;
        case 3: cout<<"CCC";break;
        case 4: cout<<"CD";break;
        case 5: cout<<"D";break;
        case 6: cout<<"DC";break;
        case 7: cout<<"DCC";break;
        case 8: cout<<"DCCC";break;
        case 9: cout<<"CM";break;
    }
    return mi_numero;
}

int millar (int mi_numero){
    int millar;
    millar = mi_numero; // 3
    switch(millar){
        case 1: cout<<"M";break;
        case 2: cout<<"MM";break;
        case 3: cout<<"MMM";break;

    }
    return 0;
}



int main (){

    int numero;

    cout<<"Ingrese un numero entero para convertilo en romano: "<<endl;
    cin>>numero; // 3891


    numero = unidades(numero);
    numero = decenas(numero);
    numero = centenas(numero);
    numero = millar(numero);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias mi estimado, me sirvio mucho! :)