# Uso de parametros en funciones c++

Tags: c++

Debo crear una función que reciba el precio de un producto y la forma de pago, debe  calcular su precio con descuento, teniendo en cuenta que el descuento es de el 20%, si la compra es de contado y 0% si es a crédito.

El problema es que cuando voy a llamar a la funcion, no se como hacer para que me reciba el parametro que deseo, en este caso quiero usar la variable (precioProducto) para cuando llame a la funcion me la relacione con la variable que cree en la misma funcion la cual es (p) para que sepa que ese valor es el que le corresponde.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main (){

    int precioProducto;

    cout<<"Ingrese el precio del producto: "<<endl;
    cin>>precioProducto;

    producto(precioProducto);


    return 0;
}

void producto (int p){

    int total,op,totalProvicional;

    switch(op){
        case 1: totalProvicional = (p * 20 / 100);
                total = p - totalProvicional;
                cout<<"El precio que debe pagar es: "<<total;break;
        case 2: cout<<"El precio que debe pagar es: "<<p;break;

        default: for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
            cout<<"Numero invalido, ingrese uno que lo sea: "<<endl;
            cin>>op;
            i--; }
    
}}
```

Este es el problema que aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El compilador te está diciendo que no sabe que la función `producto` existe porque está después de la función `main`.

Puedes arreglarlo definiéndola antes de la función `main`.

O si quieres que la función permanezca en su lugar, indícale de su existencia declarandola antes. Así:

```
void producto(int p);

int main(){
    ...
}

void producto(int p){
    ...
}
```

Si te fijas la declaración es muy parecida a la definición, solo que sin cuerpo ni corchetes y termina con `;`.

Comment: Acabo de notar que ya te había comentado sobre la declaración en otra pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/534179/169744

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! :D